# C++ Behavior of set range constructor?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, set

If I have a vector which has many duplicate elements,then I construct a set from this vector .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    vector<pair<int,int> > myvec={{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{2,1},{2,2},{2,3},{3,1},{3,2},{3,3}};
    auto comp=[](pair<int,int> a,pair<int,int> b){return a.first<b.first;};
    set<pair<int,int>, decltype(comp)> myset(myvec.begin(),myvec.end(),comp);
    for (auto p:myset)
        cout<<p.second<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, is it guaranteed that these elements will be insert to the set by the order of the vector ,like :

```
for (auto p:myvec)
myset.insert(p);
```

Comment: BTW, `for (auto p : myvec)` should be `for (const auto& p : myvec)` in this case, for betterment.

Comment: Two questions occur to me here: Firstly, have you tried looking at the documentation? Maybe the constructor of a `set` from an iterator range is defined in a way that answers your question? Secondly, `set` orders its elements anyway, so the order shouldn't make a difference. So why do you care?

Comment: Whenever you insert an element (or multiple elements) to the `set`, it's **always** ordered using your comparison function. And yes, like Ulrich Eckhardt points out, this can be found in documentation.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt He cares because he wants to confirm the iterator sequence will be scanned from beginning to end, as it would be if done manually by way of a for-loop or other logic control loop. With that comparator, the content of the set would be be different if every element of the iteration were guaranteed to be visited *once* (and obviously, only once), but the sequence was *not* guaranteed visited in-order from beginning to end. Pretty sure the OP knows the set will be ordered regardless.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I use a a.first<b.first predicate to compare the first member of the elements ,insert them into the set, and print out the second member of the elements .So order does matter ,two pairs with the same first member variable are considered equal ,but they can have completely different second member .The result would differ if I rotate the vector.

Comment: You should rethink your data structure needs. If the order in which an item is added to the set matters, you probably need a different data structure -- maybe `std::multiset`.

Comment: @RSahu No, that's not what I need .I want to sort the vector by comparing the second member first ,then construct a set from it by comparing the first member ,that's what I want ,I don't need a multiset .

Comment: @RSahu If I have several classes of students , they have their class numbers as their first member variable ,and their scores as their second member variable ,I want a set of the highest score students from each class .I just want sorted them and construct them ,two lines of codes are enough ,clear and clean .I don't want long codes ,unreadable and inefficient .

Comment: @iouvxz: Your requirement of "I want a set of the highest score students from each class" can be easily satisfied by first sorting (descending order) the vector of pairs<class_number, score> on second component of pair(i.e score) and then simply inserting all the elements from vector to set by using a BinaryPredicate which works/compares only first component of pairs from vector. Final myset will be {{1,3}{2,3}{3,3}}

Answer (score 1):

From MSVC implementation of `std::set` :

```
template<class _Iter>
void insert(_Iter _First, _Iter _Last)
{   // insert [_First, _Last)
    _DEBUG_RANGE(_First, _Last);
    for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
        this->emplace(*_First);
}
```

This method is called from the constructor you used. So, it is guarantees by this implementation. However, I am not sure that this behavior is guaranteed by the standard.

IMO and for readability, I advise that you state the order you want clearly in the comparer like this:

```
auto comp=[](std::pair<int,int> a,std::pair<int,int> b){
    if(a.first==b.first){
        return a.second<b.second;
    }
    return a.first<b.first;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

*"I have a vector which has many duplicate elements"*. By this assuming that you are only concerned with the first component of pair as its evident from your code.
Since 'set' is used then, all the elements inside 'set' will be unique and in Strict Weak Ordering i.e increasing order (as per your 'comp' Binary Predicate).
So if vector has elements(considering first part of pair) already in sorted order then, its guaranteed that elements will be inserted in set by the order of the first part of pairs in the vector.

Final value in myset = {1,1}{2,1}{3,1}.

Comment: Any documentary support ?

Comment: @iouvxz:  unique element constraints can be checked in introduction part at "http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/". If there is an element with value "abc" in set and again if a new element with same value "abc" is inserted in set then, the new element won't get inserted in set. Since you are comparing only the first part of pairs therefore the value of elements is same as first part of pairs.

Comment: My question is that is it guaranteed that the elements will be inserted from myvec.begin() to myvec.end()? What if the implementation start insert from the middle ?if I get a sorted array and want to build a set from it ,I will definitely start insert from the middle.

Comment: What if the compiler construct myvec to several small sets and merge the them into a final result ?That will be easy to optimize on a multi-core computer .